# calling stored procedure by hibernate

Tags: java, stored-procedures, join, hibernate-mapping

I'm writing a java web-based application that stores its data in Microsoft SQL server 2008 and connect to database by hibernate.

I have three tables and also three classes same as them in source code, named Form, Users and PckgForm. I want to call a stored procedure from database in one of controller classes of program. Stored procedure is as bellow, that returns all columns of three tables:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserSentForm]
@UserId varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
select * 
from Mobile.dbo.Users as us, Mobile.dbo.PckgForm as pf,
 Mobile.dbo.Form as f 
where us.UserId=@UserId and us.UserId=pf.UserId and pf.FrmId=f.FrmId
END
```

In hibernate.hbm.xml file, in sql-query tag of mentioned stored procedure I write this:

```
return alias="sentForm" class="domain.Form"
```

but by this values the returned data are mapped to class domain.Form and in my source code I can use it only as a "Form" class, while I want to use its all parameters as "Users" class and "PckgForm" class.

Any suggestions?